# Which "Select Main Type" should I select when using Eclipse to debug Play Framework based Java Project?

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

I 'eclipsified' a project - play-java-test that I created. When using Debug Configuration - which Main class should I select?

I am using Play framework 2.4.2

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't start your Play application via Eclipse. You use the `activator` command in the terminal for that. E.g. with `activator -jvm-debug 9999 run` in the folder of your application runs Play/Activator in debug mode.
For debugging Eclipse just connects to your already running application: In the Debug Configurations go to Remote Java Application, choose your project. The host is localhost and the port 9999. Then just click `debug`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Kris is right... For more information watch this
[How to attach the Eclipse debugger to a Play Framework 2.0 application](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1SCTOl0qrlM)